# Why does my SwiftUI Navigation View create a third section?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a Navigation View set up to take you from the main page to 4 different sub pages and one of them has their own sub pages. I'm fine with the first navigation view making it's own side bar but once I added the second sub page it created another side bar(See attached Image) which messes up all of the text and information. The first sub page is supposed to be a list of information that are also lists, I thought that since the main page, ContentView.swift, has a NavigationView{} that any linked views wouldn't need it again but in the subfile, Customer.swift(NavigationLink linked to content view) without the NavigationView the links are greyed out and unclickable. I could be wrong on how I thought NavigationViews worked so I added a navigation view to the sub file and it created the problem.
I'm building for macOS on Xcode 12.5 macOS Big Sur.

```
import SwiftUI

struct customers: View {
@FetchRequest(entity: Customer.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Customer.name, ascending: true)]) var customered: FetchedResults<Customer>


@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

@State var active = true
    
var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        VStack{
        Group{
    HStack{
        Text("    Name")
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.trailing)
        Text("Address")
            .padding(.leading)
            .padding(.leading)
            .padding(.trailing)
        Text("Model Number")
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.leading)
            .padding(.leading)


        Text("Serial Number")
            .padding(.leading)
            .padding(.leading)

        Text("Contract Expiration")
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .padding(.leading)

        Text("Kit Number")
        Spacer()
    }
            }
    List(customered) {that in
        NavigationLink(destination: Detail(cust: that)){
            VStack{
                    HStack{
                        Text(that.name ?? "unkown")
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                        Text(that.address ?? "unkown")
                        Text(that.modelnum ?? "unkown")
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                        Text(that.serialnum ?? "unkown")
                        Text(that.contractExperation ?? "unkown")
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                        Text(that.kitnum ?? "unkown")
                        Spacer()
                        Button("Delete"){
                            moc.delete(that)
                            try? self.moc.save()
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    }
    }
}
}
```

[image: Screenshot of Build]

I'm hoping this made sense and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If they are in the same view hierarchy, you only need one `NavigationView()`. I suspect that is the problem, but you didn't give enough information. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).